# Problema con Switch usando Sockets

Tags: java, socket

Tengo un problema en un programa que estoy haciendo en java.

Estoy usando sockets para hacer una conexión cliente/servidor con la intención de que el servidor tenga un arraylist donde voy almacenando un nombre y un stock desde el cliente.

El servidor implementa una clase con threads para que se puedan conectar varios clientes simultáneamente.

Además de esto, el servidor tiene un switch que lo uso como menú para poder consultar, dar de alta o dar de baja un producto.

El problema está en que cuando elijo una opción, es como si no se ejecutara el break, es decir, no vuelve atrás para elegir otra opción.

Os dejo el código por si alguien puede ayudar, lo agradecería muchísimo. Un saludo.

Edición:
He modificado el programa y ya funciona correctamente, pero hay un pequeño detalle y es que cuando pongo una opción incorrecta no salta el mensaje de default, es decir, no me muestra "Opción incorrecta". Edito las clases java aqui posteadas.

> Cliente

```java
package cliente;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Cliente {
    final static int PORT = 40080;
    final static String HOST = "127.0.0.1";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket sk = new Socket(HOST, PORT);

            enviarMensajesAlServidor(sk);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Cliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private static void enviarMensajesAlServidor(Socket sk) {
        OutputStream os = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            os = sk.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

            is = sk.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String linea;
            do{
            linea = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(linea);
            if(linea.startsWith("---")){
                linea = sc.nextLine();
                bw.write(linea);
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
            }
       }while(!linea.startsWith("Desconectado."));  
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Cliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                if(os != null) os.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Cliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

> Servidor

```java
package servidor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Servidor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int PORT = 40080;

        try {
            ServerSocket sk = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            while(true){
                Socket socket = sk.accept();
                HiloParaAntenderUnCliente hilo = new HiloParaAntenderUnCliente(socket);
                hilo.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }   
}
```

> HiloParaAntenderUnCliente

```java
package servidor;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class HiloParaAntenderUnCliente extends Thread{
        ArrayList<Productos> productos = new ArrayList<Productos>();
    Iterator<Productos> lista= null;
    Socket sk;
    public HiloParaAntenderUnCliente(Socket sk){
        this.sk = sk;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            is = sk.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            os = sk.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

            Inet4Address ip = (Inet4Address) sk.getInetAddress();
            String laIP = ip.getHostAddress();
            System.out.println(laIP+": se ha conectado.");

            while(true){    
            bw.write("1. Consultar\n2. Crear\n3. Borrar\n4. Aumentar/Disminuir Stock\n5. Salir");
            bw.newLine();
            int option;
            String linea;
            do{
               bw.write("---");
               bw.newLine();
               bw.flush();
               linea = br.readLine();
               option = Integer.parseInt(linea);
            }while(option<1 || option>5);

            switch(option) {

            case 1:
                if(productos.isEmpty()) {
                    bw.write("No hay productos en la lista.");
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.flush();
                    continue;
                }
                bw.write("Lista de productos: ");
                bw.newLine();
                lista = productos.iterator();
                while(lista.hasNext()) {
                    Productos p = lista.next();
                    bw.write("Producto: "+p.getNombre()+" --- Stock: "+p.getStock());
                    bw.newLine();
                }
                bw.flush();
                break;


            case 2:
                bw.write("Indique el nombre del producto para dar de alta: ");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write("---");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();

                String nombre = br.readLine();


                bw.write("Indique el stock del producto para dar de alta: ");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write("---");
                bw.newLine();

                bw.flush();
                String stock = br.readLine();

                int stock2 = Integer.parseInt(stock);
                productos.add(new Productos(nombre,stock2));
                lista = productos.iterator();
                while(lista.hasNext()) {
                    Productos p = lista.next();
                    bw.write("Producto: "+p.getNombre()+" --- Stock: "+p.getStock());
                    bw.newLine();
                }
                 bw.flush();
                break;


            case 3:
                if(productos.isEmpty()) {
                    bw.write("No hay productos en la lista.");
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.flush();
                    continue;
                }
                bw.write("Indique el nombre del producto para dar de baja: ");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write("---");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
                String n = br.readLine();

                lista = productos.iterator();
                while(lista.hasNext()) {                
                    Productos p = lista.next();
                    if(n.equals(p.getNombre())) {
                        lista.remove();
                    }
                }
                lista = productos.iterator();
                while(lista.hasNext()) {
                    Productos p = lista.next();
                    bw.write("Producto: "+p.getNombre()+" --- Stock: "+p.getStock());
                    bw.newLine();
                }
                bw.flush();
                break;

            case 4:
            bw.write("1. Aumentar Stock\n2. Disminuir Stock\n3. Volver atras");
            bw.newLine();
            int option2;
            String linea2;
            do{
               bw.write("---");
               bw.newLine();
               bw.flush();
               linea2 = br.readLine();
               option2 = Integer.parseInt(linea2);
            }while(option2<1 || option2>3);
                switch(option2){

                    case 1:
                        if(productos.isEmpty()) {
                            bw.write("No hay productos en la lista.");
                            bw.newLine();
                            bw.flush();
                            continue;
                        }
                        bw.write("Escribe el nombre del producto para aumentar el stock.");
                        bw.newLine();
                        bw.write("---");
                        bw.newLine();
                        bw.flush();
                        String ni = br.readLine();
                        lista=productos.iterator();
                        while(lista.hasNext()) {
                            Productos p = lista.next();
                            if(ni.equals(p.getNombre())) {
                                p.setStock(p.getStock()+1);
                            }
                        }
                        lista = productos.iterator();
                        while(lista.hasNext()) {
                            Productos p = lista.next();
                            bw.write("Producto: "+p.getNombre()+" --- Stock: "+p.getStock());
                            bw.newLine();
                        }
                        bw.flush();
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        if(productos.isEmpty()) {
                            bw.write("No hay productos en la lista.");
                            bw.newLine();
                            bw.flush();
                            continue;
                        }
                        bw.write("Escribe el nombre del producto para disminuir el stock.");
                        bw.newLine();
                        bw.write("---");
                        bw.newLine();
                        bw.flush();
                String no = br.readLine();
                lista=productos.iterator();
                while(lista.hasNext()) {
                            Productos p = lista.next();
                            if(no.equals(p.getNombre())) {
                            p.setStock(p.getStock()-1);
                            }
                }
                lista = productos.iterator();
                while(lista.hasNext()) {
                            Productos p = lista.next();
                            bw.write("Producto: "+p.getNombre()+" --- Stock: "+p.getStock());
                            bw.newLine();
                        }
                        bw.flush();
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        continue;
            }

            case 5:
                System.out.println(laIP+": se ha desconectado.");
                bw.write("Desconectado.");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
                System.exit(0);

                default:
                bw.write("Opcion incorrecta."); 
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
            }
        }          
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HiloParaAntenderUnCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                if(is != null) is.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(HiloParaAntenderUnCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí te das cuenta el cliente solo está preparado para recibir una línea, por lo tanto, los while donde envías varias líneas el cliente solo va a recibir una y va a desplegar el servidor dice y solicitará una nueva entrada al usuario. Por otro lado si elijes la opción consultar productos y en el caso que no existan tú mandas el mensaje pero luego continuas como si existieran (por caída del if).

Parra solucionarlo,el cliente debe saber que espera recibir del servidor. Si el cliente escoje la opcion 1 entonces debe prepararse AA recibir una serie de líneas con los productos consultados. Igual en todos los casos. Tanto server como cliente deben estar sincronizados 
En lo que se solicita y se responde.

Luego que usuario escoje la opción el cliente debe saber primero que opción escogió y para saber que tiene que esperar del servidor.

EDICION:

Siguiendo tu esquema, el cliente sólo recibe datos del servidor y solicita datos al usuario cuando el servidor los requiere. En este punto el Cliente no sabe nada de como el usuario interactua con el servidor. Lo único que el cliente tiene que saber es cuando solicitar datos al usuario y cuando terminar la conexión. Esto lo vamos hacer de la siguiente manera:
1. Si el servidor manda una linea que empieza con el caracter "?", entonces, el cliente solicitará datos al usuario y se los enviará al servidor.
2. Si el servidor manda una linea que empieza con el caracter "!", entonces, el fin de la conexión.
3. En todos los casos el cliente siempre imprime la linea que recibe del server:

Ajustamos el metodo enviarMensajesAlServidor del cliente, para adaptarlo a las reglas antedichas:

```
private static void enviarMensajesAlServidor(Socket sk) {
    OutputStream os = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        os = sk.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        is = sk.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String linea="";
        do{
            linea = br.readLine(); // recibe del servidor
            System.out.println(linea);
            if(linea.startsWith("?")){
                                    linea = sc.nextLine(); // Pide datos al usuario
                bw.write(linea); // envia al server
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
            }
       }while(!linea.startsWith("!"))

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Cliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            if(os != null) os.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Cliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

/**********************************************/
En el servidor ajustamos el metodo run():

```
 public void run() {
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        is = sk.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        os = sk.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

        Inet4Address ip = (Inet4Address) sk.getInetAddress();
        String laIP = ip.getHostAddress();
        int opcion = 0;
                    String linea=""; 
        while(true){    
            bw.write("1.Consultar -- 2.Dar de alta -- 3.Dar de baja -- 4.Salir"); // Enviamos prompt
            bw.newLine();
           opcion=0;
            do{
               bw.write("?");            // Solicitamos entrada del usuario
               bw.newLine();
               bw.flush();
               linea = br.readLine(); // Esperamos al cliente
                opcion = Integer.parseInt(linea);
            }while(opcion<1 || opcion>5);// Mientra no sea una opcion válida

            switch(opcion) {

            case 1:
                if(productos.isEmpty()) {
                    bw.write("No hay productos en la lista.");
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.flush();
                    continue; // Regresamos al prompt
                }
                bw.write("Lista de productos: ");
                bw.newLine();
                lista = productos.iterator();
                while(lista.hasNext()) {
                    Productos p = lista.next();
                    bw.write("Producto: "+p.getNombre()+" --- Stock: "+p.getStock());
                    bw.newLine();
                }
                bw.flush();
                break;


            case 2:
                bw.write("Indique el nombre del producto para añadir: ");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write("?"); // Solicitamos al cliente que pida datos al usuario
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();

                String nombre = br.readLine(); // leemos 


                bw.write("Indique el stock del producto para añadir: ");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write("?"); // Solicitamos al cliente que usuario ingrese stock
                bw.newLine();

                bw.flush();
                String stock = br.readLine(); // Leemos el stock

                int stock2 = Integer.parseInt(stock);
                productos.add(new Productos(nombre,stock2));
                lista = productos.iterator();
                while(lista.hasNext()) {
                    Productos p = lista.next();
                    bw.write("Producto: "+p.getNombre()+" --- Stock: "+p.getStock());
                    bw.newLine();
                }
                 bw.flush();
                break;


            case 3:
                bw.write("Indique el nombre del producto a borrar: ");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write("?"); // Solicitamos al cliente que usuario ingrese nombre
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
                String n = br.readLine();

                lista = productos.iterator();
                while(lista.hasNext()) {                
                    Productos p = lista.next();
                    if(n.equals(p.getNombre())) {
                        lista.remove();
                    }
                }
                lista = productos.iterator();
                while(lista.hasNext()) {
                    Productos p = lista.next();
                    bw.write("Producto: "+p.getNombre()+" --- Stock: "+p.getStock());
                    bw.newLine();
                }
                bw.flush();
                break;

            case 4:
                bw.write("Adios! ");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write("!"); // Enviamos fin de comunicación
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
                System.exit(0);

            default:
                bw.write("Opcion incorrecta."); 
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
            }

        }        
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HiloParaAntenderUnCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            if(is != null) is.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HiloParaAntenderUnCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: Ah vale, entiendo. ¿Podrías ponerme algún ejemplo? Es que la verdad ahora mismo no caigo.

Comment: Me sigue dando error, de todo modos muchas gracias.

Comment: Disculpa, solo puse un extracto de la solución, para que tengas una idea general pero al parecer no cumplió el objetivo. Déjame elaborar el ejemplo mas completo y explicado y edito la respuesta.

Comment: Ah vale gracias, es que estuve probando con el ejemplo que me pasaste y modificando cosas pero aún así no doy con la solución.

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan, acabo de leerlo y gracias a las anotaciones lo comprendo mejor, ahora mismo no puedo probarlo por que no ando en casa, pero desde que llegue lo haré y te digo, un saludo.

Comment: Gracias Juan, acabo de revisarlo y funciona perfectamente y ahora entiendo como hacer la conexión para que el cliente sepa cuando recibir y enviar mensaje dependiendo de lo que el servidor solicite, un saludo y felices fiestas!

Comment: Ok, gusto haber podido ayudarte.